# Class that returns a class

Tags: typescript

Can I translate this code into Typescript classes?

```
var A = function (argA) {
    var Constructor = function B(argB) {
        this.argB = argB;
    };

    Constructor.prototype = new OtherClass(argA);
    return Constructor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do :

```
class __Anonymous{
    argB:any;
    constructor(argB){
        this.argB = argB;
    }
}

class A {
    constructor (argA){
        return __Anonymous;
    }
}
```

Classes cannot be defined *inside* other classes / functions in typescript.

Also TypeScript will always assume that class constructors will return an instance of the class e.g

```
class Boo{boo:number;}

class Foo{
    constructor(){
        return Boo;     
    }
}

// The typescript inference 
// will always infer x to be of type Foo
var x = new Foo();
```

Additionally. Valid / complete javascript is valid typescript, so you could just use that if you really want to. e.g. <kbd>[Try it online](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20OtherClass%7B%0D%0A%09constructor%28argA%29%7B%09%09%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20A%20=%20function%20%28argA%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20Constructor%20=%20function%20B%28argB%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.argB%20=%20argB;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D;%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Constructor.prototype%20=%20new%20OtherClass%28argA%29;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Constructor;%0D%0A%7D)</kbd>:

```
class OtherClass{
    constructor(argA){      
    }
}

var A = function (argA) {
    var Constructor = function B(argB) {
        this.argB = argB;
    };

    Constructor.prototype = new OtherClass(argA);
    return Constructor;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however it won't work as I want (I changed it a bit): http://tinyurl.com/oms59q6 . In last line the compiler expects argA:number instead of argB:string. But when running the code, the generated Javascript works as expected. Is this a bug in typescript?

Comment: @kapsi Updated answer to explain why that will not work. Its not a bug. Its not designed to support such inference. Its bad class design anyways since if you do not return anything from the constructor "this" is implicitly returned. Also you cannot return literals e.g. `"someString"` from the constructor in JavaScript. So its not a reliable pattern to support.

Comment: TypeScript can however always `declare` something that works like this (using interfaces) And you can even write the javascriptish typescript yourself as I've shown. However you cannot use the `class` keyword to confuse the compiler. A `class` is different from a `new able function`